# Don't do something in Base on a Particular template page - Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have setup my nav bar in my base.html as follows

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a></li>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}">Logout</a></li>

      <li><a href="{% url 'thing_detail' slug=user.thing.slug %}">My Profile</a></li>

    {% else %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a></li>

    <li><a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
```

Now the problem is that I **Don't** want to execute the {% if %} block when user is not authenticated and when I am rendering a particular template page i.e

create_thing.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Create a Thing
- {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div id="content">
<h1> Create a Thing </h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Simply copying the contents from Base and pasting it after removing doesn't help. It still executes base.html and gets inside the if statement and shows an error because slug wont be defined until I have filled details in create_thing.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nesting the `{% if %}` clause in another `{% if not aux_var %}` clause. Whenever you don't want to execute the first if, pass `"aux_var":1` to the renderer as context.

Comment: Where do I define that variable?

Comment: In your view, pass it just like you do with your form in `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @felício Works great. BTW Can I use "and" instead of two if statements? If yes can you please tell the syntax?

Comment: Yup, {% if user.is_authenticated and not aux_var %} should work too.